# How to display environment variables as a group in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I am using Rails 5.2 application. I want to display the Environment variables as a group in the endpoint.

env_controller.rb

```
class EnvController < ApplicationController
  def index
   render json: ENV.to_h
  end
end
```

When I load http://localhost:3000/env, I see the following result

```
{
  "XDG_VTNR": "7",
  "MANPATH": "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/share/man:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.2/share/man:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/man:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man",
  "S3_SOURCE_PATH": "dev/source",
  "DB_ENV_USER": "postgres",
  "XDG_SESSION_ID": "c2",
  "rvm_bin_path": "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin",
  "S3_DESTINATION_PATH": "dev/destination",
  "SESSION": "ubuntu",
  "DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR": "localhost",
  "S3_REGION": "us-east-1"
}
```

I want to group the environment variables as follows. My expected result is as follows

```
{
  "S3": {
    "S3_SOURCE_PATH": "reports/source",
    "S3_DESTINATION_PATH": "reports/destination",
    "S3_REGION": "us-east-1"
  },
  "DB": {
    "DB_ENV_USER": "postgres",
    "DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR": "localhost"
  },
  "Others": {
    "XDG_VTNR": "7",
    "MANPATH": "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.0/share/man:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.2/share/man:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/man:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man",
    "XDG_SESSION_ID": "c2",
    "rvm_bin_path": "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin",
    "SESSION": "ubuntu"
  }
}
```

I definitely need "S3" and "DB" to be grouped. There are more variables in my application should be grouped like this. Above are the samples.

How can I display it as the above?

Comment: ENV is an enumerable. Which means you can use `group_by`, `reduce` and all other methods of Enumerable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is there any example? How can I use for my scenario?

Comment: Yes, there are examples (of grouping) in the docs (look up Enumerable#group_by). I assume if you were provided with already grouped data, you'd have no problem displaying it.

Comment: Then how can I provide grouped data to ENV?

Comment: You don't.  You take data from ENV and convert/transform it into a grouped data structure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't know how to use group_by for my scenario. I can use hash.group_by(&:name) if hash key is same. But in my case, it is different. it would be helpful if you provide solution for this

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use full form of the block: `ENV.group_by {|key, value| get_prefix(key) }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190682/discussion-between-galet-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a custom serializer. Something similar to this:

```
class EnvSerializer
  def as_json
    {
      S3: env_select('S3'),
      DB: env_select('DB'),
      Other: env_reject('S3', 'DB')
    }
  end

  private

  def env_select(prefix)
    ENV.select { |k, v| k.start_with?(prefix) }
  end

  def env_reject(*prefixes)
    ENV.reject { |k, v| k.start_with?(*prefixes) }
  end
end
```

Which would look like this in the controller:

```
class EnvController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: EnvSerializer.new.as_json
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh nice, since when `start_with?` is variadic?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev For all I can tell, since at least 1.9.1; That's as far as I went back.

Comment: @FrederikSpang: you live, you learn. This could have saved me a few loops in the past :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Know the feeling!